# ctypes weird handling of variadic arguments in functions

Tags: python, c, printf, ctypes

I am launching this snippet:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf("%f %f\n", c_float(1.0), c_double(1.0))
0.000000 1.000000
```

`printf` expects a `double` for `%f` BUT I thought floats got promoted to doubles in variadic functions, as the following C code shows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float a = 1.0f;
   double b = 1.0;
   printf("%f %f\n", a, b);
}
```

produces the expected `1.000000 1.000000`.

Am I missing something? Is the compiler doing some implicit casting in the C code?

I am using a 64-bits machine.

Comment: Indeed floats get promoted to doubles in variadic functions as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114834/printf-and-casting-float-arguments explains.

Comment: The promotion of `float` to `double` is the caller's responsibility. I would guess that ctype does not handle this correctly.

Comment: I think what happens is that ctypes doesn't know anything about the signature of `printf` unless you set it with `argtypes` and `restype`. It doesn't know it's variadic, so it's not gonna do the type promotion. As far as ctypes knows, the signature of `printf` is `int printf(char *, float, double)`, since that's how you called it and you didn't set `restype` (`int` is the default return type in `ctypes`).

Comment: @JBChouinard makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Gerhardh just to be sure, in the C snippet above, it's the C compiler that automatically promotes float into double when it builds ? The printf implementation assumes it receives only doubles ?

Comment: Yes, your expected "floats get promoted to double" is done by the compiler before calling the function. How would `printf` know what type you provide? A called function cannot see what happens in caller function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller is responsible for doing the type promotion from `float` to `double`. But `ctypes` doesn't know anything about the signature of `printf` unless you tell it. It doesn't know it's variadic and that type promotion is required.

If you don't tell `ctypes` what the signature of a function is by setting `argtypes` and `restype`, it assumes a `int` return type, and that whatever parameter you passed in match the signatures. So in your case it just assumes the signature of `printf` is:

```
int printf(char*, double, float)
```

As far as I know there is no way to define a variadic `argtypes` in `ctypes`, but it doesn't seem to do casting anyway, even if `argtypes` is set:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_double, c_double]
>>> libc.printf(c_char_p(b"%f %f\n"), c_double(1.0), c_float(1.0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "printf.py", line 5, in <module>
    libc.printf(c_char_p(b"%f %f\n"), c_double(1.0), c_float(1.0))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: `ctypes` does coerce to argtypes, but only if you don't pass explicitly.  Try `libc.printf(b'%f %f\n',1.0,1)`.  Even though using a Python float and integer as parameters, this will work.  No need for wrapping the types when argtypes is specified.